# jQuery get and text return replacement character. How to solve?

Tags: jquery

If I use:

```
$.get("url",function(data){$("#destination").text(data);})
```

in the `.text` of `#destination` the letters like èéàòùì become the [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

How do I solve it? Set the charsets is useless; I don't want to use `.replace("strange character","");`.

Comment: Trying setting the charset to `ASCII`

Comment: Make sure the encoding set in the header is at least utf-8?

Comment: open your page with notepad and resave it with utf-8

Comment: Also important to note that as per Tieson, it's the *header* not the HTML head that the encoding needs to be set in. It's fairly likely to be a server-side issue than client-side.